# Restrict deleting every field for a barcode configuration window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to restrict users deleting every field for a custom barcode configuration window which looks like this:

[image]

And this is the code that we are using to delete those fields

```
public BarcodeViewModel(IEnumerable<BatchTypeBarcodeConfig> barcode)
        {
            var barcodeDescription = new StringBuilder(64);
            int sequenceNumber = -1;
        Fields.AddRange(
            barcode
            ?.Where(field => field != null)
            .OrderBy(field => field.StartPosition)
            .Select(field =>
            {
                sequenceNumber++;

                if (field.FieldType == FieldTypeCode.STATIC)
                {
                    barcodeDescription.Append(field.FieldText);
                }
                else
                {
                    barcodeDescription.Append("(");
                    barcodeDescription.Append(field.FieldName);
                    barcodeDescription.Append(")");
                }

                var newField = new BarcodeFieldViewModel(field, sequenceNumber);
                newField.FieldLayoutChangedEvent += BarcodeFieldViewModel_FieldLayoutChangedEvent;

                return newField;
            })
            ?? Enumerable.Empty<BarcodeFieldViewModel>());

        Description = barcodeDescription.ToString();
    }
public void Delete(BarcodeFieldViewModel field)
        {
            field.FieldLayoutChangedEvent -= BarcodeFieldViewModel_FieldLayoutChangedEvent;
            Fields.Remove(field);
            UpdateFieldPositionValues();
        }
```

by this method, users can delete every barcode config field. Is there any way to restrict users to delete every barcode field? there should be at least one barcode field in the fields window.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Fields` is a `List<BarcodeFieldViewModel>`, then you can add simple validation to your `Delete` method:

```
if (Fields.Count > 1) {
    field.FieldLayoutChangedEvent -= BarcodeFieldViewModel_FieldLayoutChangedEvent;
    Fields.Remove(field);
    UpdateFieldPositionValues();
}
```

You could also use this same logic to determine if the delete button should even be visble.